# how to change the value of a attribute inside a div with jquery

Tags: jquery

here is the div

```
<div class="rating" data=""></div>
```

what i'm wondering is how i can change the value of data to say the number 5

would something like this work? or its done another way?

```
$(".rating").attr("data").val("5");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".rating").attr("data", "5");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".rating").attr("data", "5");
```

Answer (score 3):

Adhering literally to your question, the right code would be:

```
 $(".rating").attr("data", "5");
```

However, data is not a valid HTML attribute in anything other than HTML 5.

You might want to consider the jQuery [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method instead, for code that is not coupled to the latest version of HTML.

Comment: thanks for your answer its actually from a jquery plugin named jRating()